# WriteToServer does not throw exception if destination table does not exist in database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, .net-core, sqlbulkcopy

I'm using `SqlBulkCopy` to bulk insert data in C#, but it's not throwing an exception if the destination table is not present in the database.

Here is my code:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionStr);

try
{
    SqlBulkCopy objbulk = new SqlBulkCopy(connection.ConnectionString);
    objbulk.DestinationTableName = strDestinationTable;

    // bulk insert rows into database
    connection.Open();

    foreach (DataColumn clmn in dt.Columns)
        objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add(clmn.ColumnName, clmn.ColumnName);

    objbulk.WriteToServer(dt);
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    LoggingHelper.LogError(ex);
    errMsg = ex.Message ?? ex.StackTrace;
}
finally
{
    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        connection.Close();
}
```

Any way to handle this scenario?

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't throw *any* exception at all or it doesn't throw a `SqlException`? It might as well be, it throws an exception of an other type you are not catching here but somewhere else and silently ignoring. Try replacing `catch (SqlException ex)` with `catch (Exception ex)` for testing purposes ... I have never used `SqlBulkCopy` myself, but I somehow doubt, it just silently ignores such fundamental errors ...

Comment: Side point: Don't use `finally` for closing the connection, use a `using` block instead

Comment: @derpirscher Indeed it throws an `InvalidOperation` see https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlUtil.cs,a61bc274ec634b46,references and https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.data/fx/src/data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlBulkCopy.cs,2638